# ASP .NET with google map api

Tags: asp.net, api, google-maps

i am using google map api with asp .net for making a website, apart from C# which programming languages do i need to learn

Answer (score 2):

Javascript, the api is js driven.  JQuery or some other javascript library can facilitate its use too.

```
    $(function() {
        loadMaps();
    });

    function loadMaps() {
        google.load("maps", "2", { "callback": mapsLoaded });
    }

    function mapsLoaded() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));

        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Google api user control. that will facilate you all what u want . just search on
www.codeproject.com